# mod_rewrite - modify URL and continue with processing

Tags: mod-rewrite

This is excerpt from my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)$ images/$1x$2.png

# front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz)$ index.php [L]
```

What I am trying to achieve: When user goes to URL `example.com/200x100`, I want to internally rewrite the URL to `example.com/images/200x100.png`, so the application (front controller) sees the REQUEST_URI as `/images/200x100.png`, not just `200x100`. If the file /images/200x100.png exists, the application should not be launched at all.

Comment: What's the problem then?

Comment: It does not work. The first row does not modify the REQUEST_URI and the original path (200x100) lands in my PHP script.

Comment: It works fine for me, are you sure a trailing slash isn't getting appended in the request?